# Do Modern Cars Keep Event Logs?

Tags: troubleshooting, kia, niro, electric-vehicle

On a trip out of town, my Kia Niro EV failed to start a charging session at five different Level 3 (high-speed DC) chargers. The first four were commercial chargers: two different ports on an EA charger and two different EVgo chargers (at the same site). The last charger where it failed was in the shop of a Kia dealer, there the car also flashed all three of the charge status lights simultaneously -- which means "Error while charging." I'm not sure if that also happened on the other attempts as they were in bright sunlight and my prior experience has been that the problem is almost always a charger issue that can be resolved by calling tech support.

I was able to charge the car on a Level 2 charger and when I got home I took the car to the local EA charger and it started right up.

Do modern cars do any kind of logging when these things happen? I'd really like to get to the bottom of this. Between this and some other electrical problems, I'm not feeling like the car can be trusted for long trips.

Comment: My initial response to your statement about "long trips" is: *It's an EV. Of course it can't be trusted for long trips.* All joking aside, I'm sorry to say I don't have enough knowledge about EVs. No clue about Kias, but it wouldn't surprise me if Telsas did.

Comment: For the purposes of "life with EVs," or at least my life with EVs, a long trip is one that requires a charge away from home. At least in this part of the world that should be a no brainer, we are lucky enough to have plenty of chargers -- but it becomes much more tenuous when you don't know if your car will play nicely with the charger... Of course it get's even dicier when you throw in the questionable maintenance of a lot of chargers. That said, it's the first time I've had any worries...

Comment: ICEs don't keep it (the codes disappear once the fault is removed/are cleared), I